# Error: 0x80004005 in HookManager. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, hook, keyboard-hook

This question is a follow on from: [How do you disable system hotkeys in user32.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260744/how-do-you-disable-system-hotkeys-in-user32-dll) . I have not added it to chat because after googling, this appears to be an issue and I haven't found a solution which works. The error code seems to have multiple causes, one of which being a possibly corrupt dll. The fact that I can't figure out whether or not this is the case is a problem.

The code from this question comes from:
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/7294/processing-global-mouse-and-keyboard-hooks-in-c Look for the file "HookManager.Callbacks.cs"

Useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx

I keep getting the following error:

> Error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The
>   specified module could not be found at
>   Gma.UserActivityMonitor.HookManager.EnsureSubscribedToGlobalKeyboardEvents()
>   in [REDACTED DIRECTORY]HookManager.Callbacks.cs:line 401

The code causing this:

```
private static void EnsureSubscribedToGlobalKeyboardEvents()
    {
        // install Keyboard hook only if it is not installed and must be installed
        if (s_KeyboardHookHandle == 0)
        {
            //See comment of this field. To avoid GC to clean it up.
            s_KeyboardDelegate = KeyboardHookProc;
            //install hook
            s_KeyboardHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(
                WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
                s_KeyboardDelegate,
                Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(
                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]),
                0);

            //If SetWindowsHookEx fails.
            if (s_KeyboardHookHandle == 0)
            {
                //Returns the error code returned by the last unmanaged function called using platform invoke that has the DllImportAttribute.SetLastError flag set. 
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                //do cleanup

                //Initializes and throws a new instance of the Win32Exception class with the specified error. 
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode); // this line is causing this
            }
        }
    }
```

Unless I am mistaken, the culprit from the above code is:

```
s_KeyboardHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(
                WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
                s_KeyboardDelegate,
                Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(
                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]),
                0);
```

So does anyone understand what the problem here is?

**What have I tried?**

I have tried previously re-creating the entire project and copy+pasting code in case any of the program's other files were corrupted (from copying to/from USB). I had believed the problem was fixed (though I might be mistaken). The problem is now back and what I previously thought would work is not working (re-creating the project).

I will try other solutions I find online, which relate to problems with Windows. If anyone can see anything wrong with the code, please let me know. Though the code came from a very reliable source and **loads** of people have used it so this seems unlikely.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7d1a35f-3759-4217-91ba-e4416ac19d78/how-do-you-fix-error-code-0x80004005?forum=jscript
 I tried the solution which involved "regsvr32 jscript.dll" and "regsvr32 vbscript.dll". It didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You exchange last two parameters of [SetWindowsHookEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx): third parameter should be set to `IntPtr.Zero` for same process and last one is thread.

You can as well pinvoke the thread id:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, s_KeyboardDelegate, IntPtr.Zero, GetCurrentThreadId());
```